# Coding issue calling an image from folder

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with this not loading the image in the comment section now. It was working fine. I have the image saving to a folder and the uploaded filename is a uniqid  (). The comment portion actually works fine, it is just the thumbnail I'm having issues with. The image is resized using CSS so there is no thumbnail file. The images were working just fine, and now I get the comment with a broken image link. Does anyone see anything wrong with this code?

```
<?php

function setComments($conn) {
if (isset ($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message, images) values ('$uid','$date','$message','$file_name')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}       
    if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
        $errors= array();
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
        $tmp = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_ext =  end($tmp);
        $new_image_name = 'image_' . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '_' . uniqid() . '.jpg';

        $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png"."gif");

        if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG, GIF, or PNG file.";
        }

        if($file_size > 2097152) {
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
        }

        if(empty($errors)==true) {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$new_image_name);
            echo "Successfully uploaded file!";

        }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }

}
function getComments($conn) {    

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo $row['uid']."<br>";
        echo $row['date']."<br><br>";
        echo "<a href=\"uploads/{$row['images']}\"target=\"_blank\">   <img class='thumb' src=\"uploads/{$row['images']}\" />    </a>"."<br><br>";
        echo nl2br($row['message'])."<br><br>";

    }
}
```

Comment: Check the path of the images. We really can't do the debugging for you.

Comment: if the thumbnail is in another folder called "thumnails" for example, then that'll do it

Comment: what does viewing your HTML source reveal? edit: ok, you've an answer; ask them, I've left this

Comment: I would open a DevTools in chrome and check html in case there is a problem with link building.

Comment: the images are in an a folder named uploads. There is no thumbnail folder. The images are resized in a div

Answer (score 0):

dont use { } in the src just use $row['images'] its should worked

Comment: Curly braces are a thing on php, you may want to looking up